# Query Cassandra table for all rows that contain a set with given values

Tags: cassandra, cql

Assuming we have a Cassandra table called `messages` with columns:

```
id int primary key
subject text
recipients set<text>
```

How can we select all messages that have a specific set of recipients? I can't find such an option in CQL. If not possible, then can you suggest an alternative schema that would accomodate such queries?

Comment: what is other queries?

Answer (score 1):

C* 2.0 does not support secondary indexes on Collections.

From [CQL improvements in Cassandra 2.0](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0)

> Let me remark however that secondary indexing of collection columns is still not yet >supported in C* 2.0. This will come later.

In this case, you would need to model you data differently to query on recipient. Remember that C* modeling is all Query Driven, so you would want to have recipient as your rowkey.

```
create table message_recipients (recipient text, message_id int, primary key (recipient));
```

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to do that which don't involve creating a row for every possible subset of the message's recipients?

Comment: The pattern in the NoSQL world is to denormalize the data since these distributed systems run on commodity hardware with cheap storage.  Another option would be to use an external search system like Solr (this is what I do in cases like this).  If you use DataStax Enterprise Edition, it comes bundled with Solr and Hadoop to make this integration much easier.